# Twig template manager error on AWS Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, twig

I hope I find somebody who knows the Twig in details. I've developed several sites with Twig and I'm really satisfied. Now I'm trying to put the website into an AWS cloud. Generally it works fine, but sometimes after a new deploy I get the following error message:

Fatal error: Class 'Twig_TokenParser_If' not found in /var/www/html/lib/twig/lib    /Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 99 Call Stack: 0.0001 633192 1. {main}() /var/www/html/index.php:0 0.1184 1516544 2. Twig_Environment->render() /var/www/html/index.php:13 0.1184 1516544 3. Twig_Environment->loadTemplate() /var/www/html/lib/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:283 0.1186 1518664 4. Twig_Environment->compileSource() /var/www/html/lib/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:314 0.1228 1692688 5. Twig_Environment->parse() /var/www/html/lib/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:523 0.1231 1713752 6. Twig_Parser->parse() /var/www/html/lib/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:473 0.1231 1715296 7. Twig_Environment->getTokenParsers() /var/www/html/lib/twig/lib/Twig/Parser.php:74 0.1233 1731256 8. Twig_Extension_Core->getTokenParsers() /var/www/html/lib/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:694

If I set up a new environment in the cloud and I deploy exactly the same application(all files are the same), it works. I don't want to set everything on a new release.
If somebody knows what could be the error, please help me.
Thanks